# GetText from Fragment returns null but setText works

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my `MainActivity` I call a Fragment and set the boolean `mFragment` to true when its active. Now I set some Text in the `TextViews` declared in the Fragment and it works fine. But when a `Button` declared in the Fragment calls a Method in the `MainActivity` suddently `mFragment` is false and I can't use `getText` from the `TextViews` because they are null. I have no idea why this is so.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

MainFragment mainFragment;
HistoryActivity historyFragment;
boolean mFragment = false;

//....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    historyFragment = new HistoryActivity();

 if(!mFragment) {
        getMainFragment();
    }

//...SenserManager and so on

 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    if (mFragment) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

        //This works constantly:
        mainFragment.textViewX.setText("X = " + df.format(x));
        mainFragment.textViewY.setText("Y = " + df.format(y));
        mainFragment.textViewZ.setText("Z = " + df.format(z));
    }
}

public void writeEntry(){ //called in Fragment
    if(mFragment) {
        //This doesn't work (isn't even called because mFragment is false)
        String x = (String) mainFragment.textViewX.getText();
        String y = (String) mainFragment.textViewY.getText();
        String z = (String) mainFragment.textViewZ.getText();
    }
}

public void getMainFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction =   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    mFragment = true;
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

TextView textViewX;
TextView textViewY;
TextView textViewZ;
Button button;

MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    textViewX = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewX);
    textViewY = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewY);
    textViewZ = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewZ);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mainActivity.writeEntry();
        }});

    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes dude you there is no relation between `Activity` and `Fragment`. you should use[OTTO](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback interface to interact from fragment back to activity.  Please refer. It's a very recommended method. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture has many flaws. You create a fragment instance and are then calling methods on it. You can't do this in android for components such as activities, fragments, services etc (You can only do this for Java classes). You cannot simply create an object of fragment like this. All Fragments, Activities and Services in Android must go through their respective lifecycles so that they have a valid context attached to them.

Also the fragment activity interaction should be done via interfaces. Not by simply calling methods on their objects which must not be created in the first place. You might get it working but ultimately it will keep causing you problems. I recently answered two questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094039/android-app-crashing-on-run-java-lang-string-android-content-context-getpackag/37094776#37094776) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092965/android-calling-intentservice-class-from-a-service-class/37096620#37096620) which had the same problem. Seems like lot of people have this doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Your communication and a few point is wrong.

With below usage probably you wanted to access **current** MainAcitivity's method or fields. But this isn't the current instance of MainAcitivity. You just have instantiated a new one (also without lifecycle of activity)

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

So this why the mFragment boolen variable is false and also other items are null, like textviews.

You could refer below links

- http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
- http://www.truiton.com/2015/12/android-activity-fragment-communication/